# If closure of a set $D = \mathbb R^p$, then every element of $\mathbb R^p$ is a cluster point of $D$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Using the definition of closure of a set $A$ as the intersection of all closed sets in $\mathbb R^p$ containing $A$ , prove that If closure of a set $D = \mathbb R^p$, then every element of $\mathbb R^p$ is a cluster point of $D$.

**Attempt:** Suppose $clos D = $ Intersection of all closed sets in $\mathbb R^p$ containing $D$.

Then : $clos D = \mathbb R^p$

Suppose $\exists x \in \mathbb R^p $ such that there exists a neighborhood of $x$ which contains no element of $D$.

Now, we need to show a contradiction by showing that this is not possible.

And thus, every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of $D$.

How do I show this contradiction?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ that we can find an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ such that $x \in U$ and $D \cap [U-\{ x\}]= \emptyset$. This means $x$ is not a cluster point of $D$, so $x \notin \overline D$. Since $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $x \notin \overline D$ we deduce that $\mathbb{R}^p \neq \overline D$. This is our contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: @VHP no problem! Topology is my favorite.

Comment: yeah, it's a nice area. I am a little new actually.. So, I guess, I am taking my time transitioning from algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is not a cluster point, then there is an open ball $V$ centered at $x$ such that $V\cap D=\varnothing$. Then, $\mathbb{R}^p\setminus V$ is closed and contains all the $D$.

Comment: Do you mean $A = D$ here?

Comment: @VHP I do, thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)